# Python Data Wrangling: Loop through values in DataFrame and check if current iterator matches the former

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am stuck on a data wrangling problem. Below is my data:

```
Year = ['2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2010','2011','2014','2015','2016','2010','2011','2012','2015']
Type = ['WAS','WAS','BOS','BOS','WAS','BOS','BOS','BOS','WAS','WAS','BOS','BOS','BOS','BOS','BOS']
ID = ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID,'Type': Type,'Year': Year})

df
a    WAS    2010
a    WAS    2011
a    BOS    2012
a    BOS    2013
a    WAS    2014
and so on...............
```

I am trying to accomplish two things...
First - I want to loop through the dataframe and for every row, check that the id is the same and determine if the previous Type matches the current iterators type.  Then, create two new binary variables 'WAStoBOS' and 'BOStoWAS' and return 0 if there is no change at all or if the change is not the same as the variable name, and return 1 if the change is in the direction of the variable name.

For example, the output would be:

```
df
ID   Type   Year  WAStoBOS BOStoWAS
a    WAS    2010    0    0
a    WAS    2011    0    0
a    BOS    2012    1    0
a    BOS    2013    0    0
a    WAS    2014    0    1
a    BOS    2015    1    0
```

Second:
    Within the same construct, by ID, find the difference between the current rows year and the previous rows year.

The final result dataframe would be:

```
    df
ID   Type   Year  WAStoBOS BOStoWAS YearDiff
a    WAS    2010    0    0    0
a    WAS    2011    0    0    1
a    BOS    2012    1    0    1
a    BOS    2013    0    0    1
a    WAS    2014    0    1    1
a    BOS    2015    1    0    1
b    BOS    2010    0    0    0
b    BOS    2011    0    0    1
b    WAS    2014    0    1    3
b    WAS    2015    0    0    1
b    BOS    2016    1    0    1
c    BOS    2010    0    0    0
c    BOS    2011    0    0    1
c    BOS    2012    0    0    1
c    BOS    2015    0    0    3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

This edit is after Scotts suggestion.

For example, your code incorrectly assigns a 1 to an instance where the ID and Type change.  Where if an ID changes, we don't care what the previous Type was...  Ill change the data frame below a little to account for a change in ID and Type while also showing what the desired output should be...

```
        df
ID   Type   Year  WAStoBOS BOStoWAS YearDiff
a    WAS    2010    0    0    0
a    WAS    2011    0    0    1
a    BOS    2012    1    0    1
a    BOS    2013    0    0    1
a    WAS    2014    0    1    1
**a    BOS    2015**    1    0    1
**b    WAS    2010**    0    0    0
b    BOS    2011    1    0    1
b    WAS    2014    0    1    3
b    WAS    2015    0    0    1
**b    WAS    2016**    0    0    1
**c    BOS    2010**    0    0    0
c    BOS    2011    0    0    1
c    BOS    2012    0    0    1
c    BOS    2015    0    0    3
```

I asterisks beside the instances where there is a change in ID and Type for your reference.  Thank you for your help, I never thought about using assign.

Comment: I feel like pd.Series.shift() is going to be what you want here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT assigning binary with 'ID' in consideration:

```
df.assign(WAStoBOS=df.groupby('ID')['Type'].transform(lambda x: ((x == 'BOS') & (x.shift(1) == 'WAS')).astype(int)),
          BOStoWAS=df.groupby('ID')['Type'].transform(lambda x: ((x == 'WAS') & (x.shift(1) == 'BOS')).astype(int)),
          YearDiff=df.groupby('ID')['Year'].transform(lambda x: x.astype(int).diff().fillna(0)))
```

Let's do this in one statement:

```
df.assign(WAStoBost=((df.Type == 'BOS') & (df.shift(1).Type == 'WAS')).astype(int),
          BOStoWAS=((df.Type=='WAS')&(df.shift(1).Type == 'BOS')).astype(int),
          YearDiff=df.groupby('ID')['Year'].transform(lambda x: x.astype(int).diff().fillna(0)))
```

Output:

```
   ID Type  Year  BOStoWAS  WAStoBost  YearDiff
0   a  WAS  2010         0          0       0.0
1   a  WAS  2011         0          0       1.0
2   a  BOS  2012         0          1       1.0
3   a  BOS  2013         0          0       1.0
4   a  WAS  2014         1          0       1.0
5   a  BOS  2015         0          1       1.0
6   b  BOS  2010         0          0       0.0
7   b  BOS  2011         0          0       1.0
8   b  WAS  2014         1          0       3.0
9   b  WAS  2015         0          0       1.0
10  b  BOS  2016         0          1       1.0
11  c  BOS  2010         0          0       0.0
12  c  BOS  2011         0          0       1.0
13  c  BOS  2012         0          0       1.0
14  c  BOS  2015         0          0       3.0
```

Comment: Thanks Scott - This is very close to my desired output. The only addition needed is to make sure that the ID is accounted for when assigning the binary flag for 'WAStoBOS' and 'BOStoWAS'.  I modified the original desired table a bit to show you what I mean.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, modified the output.

Comment: Thanks Scott - that is exactly what I was looking for!